# Creating A Simple AJAX / jQuery / PHP SELECT * / JSON

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, json

Basically I want to know how I can pass an array from PHP to JSON and be able to use it in my js file, where the jQuery is, and with jQuery I'm using the $.ajax({}).

I have so far:

```
$db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=names', 'username', 'password');
$stmt = $db->query('SELECT * FROM names ORDER BY name DESC');
$results = $stmt->fetchAll();

$namesArray = array();
foreach ($results as $row) {
    array_push($namesArray, '<li>' . $row['name'] . '</li>');
}

echo json_encode($namesArray);
```

As for the jQuery / AJAX, I'm not really sure how I should go about it. The only thing I want to do in PHP is make it select all the data from the database, (which has one col, names), and store them in an array via the foreach, and I pushed them to a separate array.

How would I go about the jQuery / AJAX? I've searched everywhere and the only thing I can find is how to make search functions with AJAX, although I don't want to search for one name, I want every name in the database to show up. Thanks in advance.

**Update:**

in my index.html file I have linked the .js file, and also in there I have a unordered list with the class: "names".

So, for my jQuery file, or .js file, I have

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        url: "post.php",
        data: { },
        cache: false,
        success: function() {

        }
    });
});
```

but I'm not sure on what goes in the data variable, and also the success function I'm confused on too.

If I have forgotten any vital information on figuring this out please let me know :)

Comment: for that u need jQuery code , where it is ? U need to to call $.ajax in jQuery code that u dont posted.

Comment: For the backend, you're doing great.
On the front-end, you should use AJAX in your webpage in order to communicate with backend.
Check the following tutorial: http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ajax_intro.asp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be something like this with jQuery AJAX:

```
$.ajax({
    type : 'POST',
    url : 'path/to/your/file.php',
    success : function(data){
        console.log(JSON.parse(data));
    },
});
```

Comment: Thanks, I had something like this, but where does "data" come from. When I encode the array, how does the jQuery file know what the array is, or where it's coming from?

Comment: `data` is everything you've `echo`. And it comes from the file defined in `url`.

Comment: Alright, thanks that bit is pretty helpful. :) Although I've seen people define a data variable inside the $.ajax({data: ????}) like that. What is that for?

Comment: I've just figured it out! Thanks a lot for the help, man. I was trying to do a foreach from the JSON encoded array from PHP but it turns out I was thinking too hard and all I had to do was $('.names').html(data); I was thinking it was more complicated. Thanks a lot for your help :)